# Get Firebase Child as ArrayList to be passed through Intent

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to desigining Firebase Database. So I have this tree which looked like this:

[I can't display an Image. Here's the Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uTcE.png)

The problem is I can't managed to fetch all of the "jam" data, insert it into an ArrayList, passes it through intent and then displayed it. Here's what I've come up until now:

MapFragment.java

```
Double latitude_, longitude_;
    String nama_tempat, kategori, alamat, nomor_telepon, harga, gambar;
    ArrayList<String> jamOperasional = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
.
for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("places").getChildren())
                {
                    latitude_ = child.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    longitude_ = child.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    nama_tempat = child.child("nama").getValue(String.class);
                    kategori = child.child("kategori").getValue(String.class);
                    alamat = child.child("alamat").getValue(String.class);
                    harga = child.child("harga").getValue(String.class);
                    nomor_telepon = child.child("nomor_telepon").getValue(String.class);
                    gambar = child.child("gambar").getValue(String.class);
                    for (DataSnapshot operasional : child.child("jam").getChildren()) {
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("senin").getValue(String.class));
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("selasa").getValue(String.class));
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("rabu").getValue(String.class));
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("kamis").getValue(String.class));
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jumat").getValue(String.class));
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("sabtu").getValue(String.class));
                        jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("minggu").getValue(String.class));

                    }
DetailsModel detail = new DetailsModel(latitude_, longitude_,nama_tempat,
                            kategori,alamat,harga,nomor_telepon,gambar,jamOperasional);
.
.
.
DetailsModel detail = detailMarkerMap.get(marker);
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Judul", detail.getNama_tempat());
                bundle.putString("Alamat", detail.getAlamat());
                bundle.putString("Harga", detail.getHarga());
                bundle.putString("NomorTelepon", detail.getNomor_telepon());
                bundle.putDouble("Latitude", detail.getLatitude());
                bundle.putDouble("Longitude", detail.getLongitude());
                bundle.putString("Gambar", detail.getGambar());
                bundle.putStringArrayList("Jam", detail.getJamOperasional());
                mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                getActivity().startActivity(mainIntent);
```

DetailsActivity.java

```
for(int i = 0; i < bundle.getStringArrayList("Jam").size(); i++) {
            placeHours.append(bundle.getStringArrayList("Jam").get(i) + "\n");
        }
```

This gave me null output for about 10 lines ++. At least if it's wrong, it should have printed 7 null outputs. I hope this information helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please verify if all of those variables are `not null` -> `latitude_`, `longitude_`, `nama_tempat` and so on. To use those variables between activities, i recomand you using `SharedPreferences` if you need to have them within all activities of your app or if you want to have them only in the second activity, please use this code:

```
//In First Activity
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Judul", detail.getNama_tempat());
intent.putExtra("Alamat", detail.getAlamat());
intent.putExtra("Harga", detail.getHarga());
//and so on
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

and this code, to get those values back:

```
//In Second Activity
String Judul = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("Judul");
String Alamat = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("Alamat");
String Harga = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("Harga");
//and so on
```

To get and the other values in a correct way, please use this code:

```
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("senin").getValue(String.class));
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("selasa").getValue(String.class));
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("rabu").getValue(String.class));
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("kamis").getValue(String.class));
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("jumat").getValue(String.class));
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("sabtu").getValue(String.class));
jamOperasional.add(operasional.child("jam").child("minggu").getValue(String.class));
```

As you probably see, i have removed that `for loop`, because it isn't needed and added the new `.child("jam")` for every coresponding variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My problem is fetching the childs of "Jam", not the others. Judul, alamat, and harga displays the output perfectly.

Comment: I see, so it doesn't have to be on a for loop. It works this way. Many thanks